# Powershell Functions with multiple params

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am attempting to write a function to compress files using 7zip, but I am having issues passing multiple parameters to the function.

```
$In = "C:\test\gateways_25357_20140407000204.pcap"
$Out = "C:\test\gateways_25357_20140407000204.zip"


function CompressFile([string]$Output,[string]$Input) {
    Write-Host $Output
    write-host $Input
    $7zipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    $Arguments = "a","-tzip",$Output,$Input
    & $7zipPath $Arguments

}

CompressFile $Out $In
```

My results of this code is the compressing of the files in the working directory of this script and the output goes to the correct location c:\test.

What exactly am I doing wrong here with passing in the $Input parameter?

Answer (score 2):

$Input is a powershell automatic variable, try changing the name. 
see

```
$In = "C:\test\gateways_25357_20140407000204.pcap"
$Out = "C:\test\gateways_25357_20140407000204.zip"


function CompressFile([string]$Outputz, [String]$Inputz) {
    Write-Host $Outputz
    write-host $Inputz
}
Write-Host $Out
write-host $In
CompressFile $Out $In
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx